# Regexplanation: difference between [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9] vs [a-zA-Z0-9] with * vs +

Tags: regex

Comparing:

```
echo 'abc def' | sed 's/\([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]+\) \([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]+\)/\2 \1/' 
abc def

echo 'abc def' | sed 's/\([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*\) \([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*\)/\2 \1/' 
def abc

echo 'abc def' | sed 's/\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\) \([a-zA-Z0-9]+\)/\2 \1/' 
abc def

echo 'abc def' | sed 's/\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\) \([a-zA-Z0-9]*\)/\2 \1/' 
def abc
```

The intention is to swap 'abc' and 'def', why are some of these examples not working?

In the + versions:
I expected [a-zA-Z0-9]+ would match things like 'a', 'ab' and 'abc' (up to the space) and swap them.
I expected the [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]+ version to match  'ab' and 'abc', which would work to

Is there any difference between the * versions, besides that the one with a single?

Isn't [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]* the same as [a-zA-Z0-9]+? That is, match a string of at least one alphanumeric character?

Answer (score 3):

The POSIX "Basic" regex language used by sed does not have the `+` operator, so `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` matches exactly one alphanumeric character – followed by a literal plus-sign.

It does have the `\{x,y\}` operator to accept the specified number of matches, for example:

```
$ echo 'abc def' | sed 's/\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{2,\}\) \([a-zA-Z0-9]\{2,\}\)/\2 \1/'
def abc
```

Use `sed -E` to enable the "Extended" regex mode, where `+` is a special character. This will also change how parentheses work – in extended mode, bare `(` `)` are used for capture groups and similarly bare `{` `}` are used for number of matches, the opposite of basic mode.

```
$ echo 'abc def' | sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]+) ([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]+)/\2 \1/'
def abc

$ echo 'abc def' | sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}) ([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})/\2 \1/'
def abc
```

GNU sed/grep also allow you to use `\+` in basic mode but this is not portable to other operating systems. See `info "(sed)BRE syntax"` and `info "(sed)ERE syntax"` (or `man 7 regex`) for a comparison of the two modes.